# Translate Assimp 3D Models also rotates

Tags: c++, opengl, assimp

[image: This is the view before translate, which is correct.]
[image: This is the view after translate, which is incorrect.]

I have a 3D Model in an OpenGL (C++) loaded using Assimp.
I need to move this model around the screen (translate) like it is always facing the camera in the X and Y axis (no Z axis).
It would be like moving this model like it is 2D only (but of course if I rotate it, it would show the Z axis as well).

my render function is :

```
    camX = CamY = 0;  
    camZ = 5;  
    lookatX = lookatY = lookatZ = 0;  

    void C3DModel::render(void)  
    { 

        static float step = 0.0f;  
        setCamera(camX, camY, camZ, lookatX, lookatY, lookatZ);  
        translate(-3, 1, 0); // here is the issue . 
        scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);  
        rotate(step, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); 
    }

    void C3DModel::translate(float x, float y, float z) 
    {

       float aux[16];

       setTranslationMatrix(aux, x, y, z);
       multMatrix(modelMatrix, aux);
       setModelMatrix();
   }

   void C3DModel::setTranslationMatrix(float *mat, float x, float y, float z)
   {

       setIdentityMatrix(mat, 4);
       mat[12] = x;
       mat[13] = y;
       mat[14] = z;
   }

   void C3DModel::setScaleMatrix(float *mat, float sx, float sy, float sz)
   {

       setIdentityMatrix(mat, 4);
       mat[0] = sx;
       mat[5] = sy;
       mat[10] = sz;
   }

   void C3DModel::setRotationMatrix(float *mat, float angle, float x, float y, float z)
   {
       float radAngle = DegToRad(angle);
       float co = cos(radAngle);
       float si = sin(radAngle);
       float x2 = x * x;
       float y2 = y * y;
       float z2 = z * z;

       mat[0] = x2 + (y2 + z2) * co;
       mat[4] = x * y * (1 - co) - z * si;
       mat[8] = x * z * (1 - co) + y * si;
       mat[12] = 0.0f;

       mat[1] = x * y * (1 - co) + z * si;
       mat[5] = y2 + (x2 + z2) * co;
       mat[9] = y * z * (1 - co) - x * si;
       mat[13] = 0.0f;

       mat[2] = x * z * (1 - co) - y * si;
       mat[6] = y * z * (1 - co) + x * si;
       mat[10] = z2 + (x2 + y2) * co;
       mat[14] = 0.0f;

       mat[3] = 0.0f;
       mat[7] = 0.0f;
       mat[11] = 0.0f;
       mat[15] = 1.0f;
   }


   void C3DModel::rotate(float angle, float x, float y, float z) 
   {

      float aux[16];

      setRotationMatrix(aux, angle, x, y, z);
      multMatrix(modelMatrix, aux);
      setModelMatrix();
  }

  void C3DModel::scale(float x, float y, float z)
  {
      float aux[16];

      setScaleMatrix(aux, x, y, z);
      multMatrix(modelMatrix, aux);
      setModelMatrix();
  }

  void C3DModel::setIdentityMatrix(float *mat, int size)
  {
     // fill matrix with 0s
     for (int i = 0; i < size * size; ++i)
         mat[i] = 0.0f;
     // fill diagonal with 1s
     for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        mat[i + i * size] = 1.0f;
  }

  void C3DModel::multMatrix(float *a, float *b) 
  {

     float res[16];

     for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) 
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) 
         {
             res[j * 4 + i] = 0.0f;
             for (int k = 0; k < 4; ++k) 
             {
                 res[j * 4 + i] += a[k * 4 + i] * b[j * 4 + k];
             }
         }
     }
     memcpy(a, res, 16 * sizeof(float));
  }

  void C3DModel::setModelMatrix() 
  {
      glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, matricesUniBuffer);
      glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ModelMatrixOffset, MatrixSize, modelMatrix);
      glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
 }

 void C3DModel::crossProduct(float *a, float *b, float *res) 
 {
     res[0] = a[1] * b[2] - b[1] * a[2];
     res[1] = a[2] * b[0] - b[2] * a[0];
     res[2] = a[0] * b[1] - b[0] * a[1];
 }

 // Normalize a vec3
 void C3DModel::normalize(float *a)
 {

     float mag = sqrt(a[0] * a[0] + a[1] * a[1] + a[2] * a[2]);
     a[0] /= mag;
     a[1] /= mag;
     a[2] /= mag;
 }

 void C3DModel::setCamera(float posX, float posY, float posZ, float lookAtX, float lookAtY, float lookAtZ) 
 {

     float dir[3], right[3], up[3];
     up[0] = 0.0f;  up[1] = 1.0f;   up[2] = 0.0f;
     dir[0] = (lookAtX - posX);
     dir[1] = (lookAtY - posY);
     dir[2] = (lookAtZ - posZ);
     normalize(dir);
     crossProduct(dir, up, right);
     normalize(right);
     crossProduct(right, dir, up);
     normalize(up);
     float viewMatrix[16], aux[16];
     viewMatrix[0] = right[0];
     viewMatrix[4] = right[1];
     viewMatrix[8] = right[2];
     viewMatrix[12] = 0.0f;
     viewMatrix[1] = up[0];
     viewMatrix[5] = up[1];
     viewMatrix[9] = up[2];
     viewMatrix[13] = 0.0f;
     viewMatrix[2] = -dir[0];
     viewMatrix[6] = -dir[1];
     viewMatrix[10] = -dir[2];
     viewMatrix[14] = 0.0f;
     viewMatrix[3] = 0.0f;
     viewMatrix[7] = 0.0f;
     viewMatrix[11] = 0.0f;
     viewMatrix[15] = 1.0f;
     setTranslationMatrix(aux, -posX, -posY, -posZ);
     multMatrix(viewMatrix, aux);
     glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, matricesUniBuffer);
     glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ViewMatrixOffset, MatrixSize, viewMatrix);
     glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
 }
```

Comment: Can you share all the code for those functions (translate, scale, rotate & setCamera)?

Comment: @Mrax Why do you do `rotate(step, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);`?

Comment: @Gerard097, just add the code that you asked, sorry for not posting it before.

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz, I also need to rotate the object after translate it.

Comment: I got this code from : https://www.lighthouse3d.com/cg-topics/code-samples/importing-3d-models-with-assimp/

Comment: I'm a bit confused @Mrax, your question says *Translate Assimp Models also rotates*, then I see you `rotate` it and then you say you have to, which I get it if you want it to always face the camera. Can you clarify what is exactly your issue and what you want? Cheers

Comment: you should keep your ```translation``` and ```rotation``` in 2 different matrices. Not in your ```model``` one for now. And at each frame in the render function you build your ```model``` matrix by creating a new one. You should apply your rotation first then your translation. See this 2 matrices like the rotation who apply on your object first, then where to put it on screen.

Comment: Do you search for [Billboards](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/billboards-particles/billboards/)?

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz, sorry about the confusion. Please forget about the rotation, I am attaching the pics.
As they say a picture is worth a thousand words ...

Comment: @DraykoonD, thanks for the reply!
You saying that I need to create one matrice for translation and another one for rotation ?

Comment: @Rabbid76, actually I didn't know it exists. Thank you for the tip. I wll try that out!

Comment: Elaborating on what @DraykoonD said. Every transform can be decomposed into a translation matrix, a scaling matrix and a rotation matrix. The final transform is constructed by multiplying these matrices (order matters here). You should read about that. Why not start with a simple 2D project instead? Getting a hango of it, and then jumping to 3D? Cheers!

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz, thank you so much for the reply!
Yes, I understand this is a newbie question, the thing is, this a small part of a 6 years project, and this is my weakest knowledge, since it doesn't seem too complicated to solve, I tried to skip a few lessons and get it finally, over with.
Thank you Javier, once again!
Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i will try is to separate the rotation of your object and the translation requested for your screen position, in 2 different matrices.

At each frame, I would compute the rotation matrice with the code inside your `C3DModel::setRotationMatrix` and the translation with `C3DModel::setTranslationMatrix`, combine them in a fresh new model matrice and apply it to your object. Keep in mind that the order matters, if you rotate first the object will turn around the origin in your `obj` file, if you rotate after the translation it will rotate around the worl origin (like a planet around the sun, the sun would be the origin).

In the end, it would looks like:

```
void C3DModel::render(void){

    float* rotation = createRotation(angle, x, y, z);
    float* translation = createTranslation(x, y, z);
    float* updatedModel = mul(rotation, translation) //order matters
    setModel(updatedModel);
}
```

Comment: Dear Draykoon D! You are the best!!! Saved my life in just a few line of code! Thank you so much for taking the time! Best wishes!!!

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have enough points to close my own questions 

Comment: No... I can’t do anything pretty much. Tried to upvote your answer and it says that was compute, but I don’t have enough points to upvote. Truth is, I tried to use stackoverflow just twice. And in both times people were rude, so I decided not to use again. But this time, since I was very close to end a 6 years old project, and I was wasting too long on getting this right, I tried to use it again, was kinda of afraid to be honest. But thanks God this time people were nice. And you solved my problem. So, now I will consider getting more points.